# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when modifying data returned by CFDataGetBytePtr

Tags: heap-memory, readonly, objective-c++, dataprovider, cgimageref

Making long story short, I want to capture a window and then modify the bytes buffer:

```
struct CaptureObject
    {
        unsigned char* bgraData;
        CFDataRef bgraDataRef;
        CGDataProviderRef provider;
        int width;
        int height;
        int bytesPerRow;
    };

CaptureObject obj;

CGImageRef windowImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(captureCGRect, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, windowId, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming | kCGWindowImageShouldBeOpaque);

obj.width = CGImageGetWidth(windowImage);
obj.height = CGImageGetHeight(windowImage);
obj.bytesPerRow = CGImageGetBytesPerRow(windowImage);

obj.provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(windowImage);
obj.bgraDataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(obj.provider);
obj.bgraData = const_cast<unsigned char*>(CFDataGetBytePtr(obj.bgraDataRef));

//Read and right obj.bgraData;

CGImageRelease(windowImage);
CFRelease(browserImage.bgraDataRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(browserImage.provider);
```

I can read the data but getting a crash when trying to write to this buffer. 
As clearly noticed in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDataRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFDataGetBytePtr) 'CFDataGetBytePtr':

> Returns a read-only pointer to the bytes of a CFData object.

But what does it actually means? If this is only a compilation syntax, I thought that 'const_cast' should solve this. So My question is how the OS mange to allocate the object in "read only" segment (something like "code segment");

P.S. I'm trying to avoid using 'CFDataGetByte' that actually copies the data because it is too expensive for my purpose.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145374/error-in-for-loop-when-rewriting-values)?

Comment: @Droppy thanks for the reference, I'll take a look on it but it seems that it is more or less the same method as using 'CFDataGetByte' that copies the bytes - which I want to avoid. And it doesn't answer how it is being implemented by the compiler/os.

Comment: Did you look at [the solution](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/108072-exc-bad-access-in-ios-6-but-not-in-ios-5.html) that was linked to that question (to use a mutable copy of the data)?

Comment: @Droppy yes I did. But as I said, it involves copy :)